# Metal Running Horizontally Through Center of 2x4 Bracing?

Tags: electrical, framing, drill, metal

I am trying to drill a wider hole through horizontal bracing in our wall in order to run some low voltage wire. Using a flexible installer bit, am able to get about 1/2 way through what I think is a 2x4. However, then end up running into what seems to be metal.

As far as **apparent** mechanicals, there are no HVAC ducts, wiring, or plumbing fixtures nearby.

Got my scope out and it appears this is some form of metal in the *center* of the 2x4. I don't think it is sandwiched between two 2x4s.

[image: cross section of 2x4 with metal]

Sorry for poor quality, phone photo of scope screen. You can see what looks to be the metal as the darker, shiney part below the existing hole:

[image: scope image of horizontal bracing showing possible metal]

Any ideas on what this is? Can I safely drill through it? Thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Metal in the middle of a single 2x4 usually is a nail/screw.  For placing wire in hole, would try making another hole in different place.  Don't need sharp metal near wire.

Comment: Is that on the back side of the board? Possibly a nail plate metal running horizontally. The word apparently bothers me.